# What process does a cron job run under?

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi, cron, raspbian

On a Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian, I discovered that I can use `crontab -e` and then add a line like `@reboot sudo /root/.nvm/v0.10.26/bin/node /root/tweetmonkey-raspi &` to the table to start a node process on boot.
I can't figure out how to quickly kill that process. I don't see it in `ps -e`. What process is that running under?

Comment: if you want to start a daemon process at boot, you probably should use `systemd`/`System V init`/`upstart` or whatever your init daemon is. or use `rc.local`. But abusing `cron` for this, sounds like a *bad idea*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron jobs are started by `cron` or `crond`, which will spawn `sh` to run your command. However, your command forked to run in the background, and then finished executing, so the `node` process is reparented to the root process, `init`.